# Create a draggable, re-sizable box in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, draggable, resizable

I've searched all over for a way to create a View that has both draggable and resizable functionality. I have come close with the `react-native-gesture-handler` package but the resizable corners are where I'm left stumped.

```
<PanGestureHandler
                onGestureEvent={this._onDragGestureEvent}
                onHandlerStateChange={this._onDragHandlerStateChange}
            >
                <Animated.View style={styles.wrapper}>
                    <RotationGestureHandler
                        ref={this.rotationRef}
                        simultaneousHandlers={this.pinchRef}
                        onGestureEvent={this._onRotateGestureEvent}
                        onHandlerStateChange={this._onRotateHandlerStateChange}>
                        <Animated.View style={styles.wrapper}>
                            <PinchGestureHandler
                                ref={this.pinchRef}
                                simultaneousHandlers={this.rotationRef}
                                onGestureEvent={this._onPinchGestureEvent}
                                onHandlerStateChange={this._onPinchHandlerStateChange}>
                                <Animated.View collapsable={false}>
                                    <Image background={true} width={Dimensions.get('window').width}
                                           source={{ uri: `<BACKGROUND IMAGE>` }}
                                           defaultSource={require('../../assets/icon.png')}>
                                        <Animated.View
                                            style={[
                                                styles.box,
                                                {
                                                    width: this.state.boxWidth,
                                                    height: this.state.boxHeight,
                                                    transform: [
                                                        { perspective: 200 },
                                                        { scale: this._scale },
                                                        { rotate: this._rotateStr },
                                                        { rotateX: this._tiltStr },
                                                        { translateX: this._translateX },
                                                        { translateY: this._translateY }
                                                    ],
                                                },
                                            ]}
                                        />
                                    </Image>
                                </Animated.View>
                            </PinchGestureHandler>
                        </Animated.View>
                    </RotationGestureHandler>
                </Animated.View>
            </PanGestureHandler>
```

My question is has anyone ever come across or has an example of resizable corner handles in React Native?

Comment: Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

check this:

https://github.com/brucelin0325/react-native-resizable-flex-panes/blob/master/Mycomponent.js

the componentWillMount() will help you i guess?

Comment: Thanks for the response, that may help. When it's solved I will post the answer.